# why it is giving undefined when i am trying to get parent nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I want to get all parent node text . when user Click home button it should give parents node elemnent not id of that ? I am using jstree .

In my demo 
Expected out put is  "a" and "b". ?

```
   $('#home').click(function () {
         alert('home');
          alert($('#tree').jstree(true).get_node('null').children);

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/40/

Comment: Why are you passing `'null'` to `get_node`?

Comment: Also please note that `'null' != null`.

Comment: because they don't have parents

Comment: I need top parents/ first layer  out put is "a" and "b"

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSTree but I'm reading their docs and can't find where exactly they specify the need to pass either `null` or `'null'` to `get_node`.

Comment: It would be very weird for a library to require you to pass a string containing `'null'` instead of passing the actual `null` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#home').click(function () {
    var roots = $('#tree').jstree(true).get_children_dom($('#tree'));
    roots.each(function(x, k) { alert(k.id); });
});
```

In the function `each`, you get the IDs of the root nodes, so you should add your code there.

If you want the text of the root nodes, you can use the function `get_text` for each nodes that we identified before:

```
$('#home').click(function () {
    var tree = $('#tree').jstree(true);
    var roots = tree.get_children_dom($('#tree'));
    roots.each(function(x, k) {
        alert(tree.get_text($('#'+k.id)));
    });
});
```

Code in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/41/

Comment: I don't want id ..I want text..:(

Comment: can you please use fiddle

Comment: can we get child of "b" when user click button on child only text

Comment: expected output is "b-a","b-b"

Comment: get this out put when user click "child button"

Comment: It will be better if you write your doubts entirely in only one question.
Your code already catch the event `select_node.jstree`, so it might be enough...

Comment: hmm ..yes sir can you give me last time on fiddle .next time i will write

Comment: actually that was for select .I need without select

Comment: if user click "child " button it gives child of "b"

Comment: You mean that irrespective of the node selected by the user, the button "Child" should give always the children of the node "b"?

Comment: yes that write so that I use that code in other place

Comment: This is the code that uses the jsTree API: http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/42/ 
However, according to the API, the children must be rendered - this means that if the node "b" is not expanded, the function does not return anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52001/discussion-between-user3530755-and-winterlude)

Comment: Yes. If you need somthing different, please write entirely your requirements.